# Namespaces and resources on Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, namespaces, routes

I am developping an app with a backoffice (**admin**) which is restricted to some users, in order to modify content. And on the other side I have a webservice (**api**) which is accessed by clients.

So I've seperated the two parts in namespaces, and I realised that when I used scaffolding for a resource like questions for instance, the generated controller assumes the resource is *admin::questions*, but that's not what I wanted.

I expect to have:

```
/admin/questions to handle my questions (controller admin/questions_controller.rb)

/api/questions to serve my questions  (controller api/questions_controller.rb)
```

But in both cases, it's the same model.

Should I keep on using namespace or or use module in my routes?
Does it go against the philosophy of rails resources?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Often the reason for using namespaces is to do exactly what the scaffolding id generating.  That is, you *want* a different controller for the GUI and the API.  Consider that if you have different controllers, you will not have a cleaning respond_to (and might be able to take out the respond_to).

Comment: That's not to say what you are doing is wrong.  The respond_to is there for just such a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

By running `rails generate scaffold -h` I saw an option called `--skip-namespace`. Is that what you're looking for?

From the documentation:

```
Usage:
  rails generate scaffold NAME [field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]] [options]

Options:
    [--skip-namespace]                        # Skip namespace (affects only isolated applications)
```